# $\|A\|_2 \le \|b\|_2 \Rightarrow |b^TAb| \le \|b\|_2^3$

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

> Let $A \in \Bbb S^{n}$ symmetric matrices and $b \in \Bbb R^n$.
>
> If $\|A\|_2 \le \|b\|_2$, then $|b^TAb| \le \|b\|_2^3$,
>
> where $\|A\|_2$ is the maximum singular value of $A$ and $\|b\|_2$ is the $2$-norm of $b$.

I see that $|b^TAb| \le \|b\|_2 \|Ab\|_2$ by the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, but from here I'm having trouble.

I also see that $\|b\|_2 \|A\|_2 \|b\|_2 \le \|b\|_2^3$, but I'm not sure how to relate $\|b\|_2 \|A\|_2 \|b\|_2$ and $|b^TAb|$.

Comment: Outline: $||Ab||_2^2 = (Ab)^T(Ab) = b^TA^TAb$. Now we know that (by eigenvalue decomposition say) that the max of $(b^TA^Tb)/(b^Tb)$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$ which is the largest singular value of $A$ squared. You should be able to finish from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with a certain vector norm and its associated matrix norm, in the sense that
$$
\|A\| = \sup_{x \ne 0}\frac{\|A x\|}{\|x\|}.
$$

In this case it is easy to show that $\| A x\| \leq \|A\| \|x\|$, which allows you to say that
$$
|b^T A b | \leq \|b\| \|A b\| \leq \|b| \|A\| \|b\| \leq \| b\|^3.
$$